# How To 'check' A Checkbox In A JQuery Test

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I am testing a function which changes a div's display from 'none' to 'block' when a checkbox is 'checked'. The code works on the website and I have another test on the same piece of code which passes (Javascript checks to see if the checkbox is 'checked' on page load. If not it changes the div to 'none').

The test:

```
QUnit.test("optional fields visible when checkbox selected", function (assert) {
      assert.equal($('#optional_fields').css('display'), 'none');
      $('#id_taken_test_before').prop('checked', true);
      assert.equal($('#optional_fields').css('display'), 'block');
    });
```

The associated html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
      <div id="div_id_taken_test_before" class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="taken_test_before" class="checkboxinput custom-control-input" 
        id="id_taken_test_before">
        <label for="id_taken_test_before" class="custom-control-label">Have you taken the test 
        before</label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And the associated javascript code:

```
$("#div_id_taken_test_before").change(function(){
    var questions = document.getElementById("optional_fields");

    if($('#id_taken_test_before').is(':checked')){
       questions.style.display = "block";
    }else{
        questions.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

I am trying to 'check' the checkbox, which then should trigger my javascript and change the 'optional_fields' div to 'block'.

The :checked event never fires. Ive tried many things-

```
(div_id_taken_test_before').prop...
.click()
```

etc, but just cant get this checkbox to change to 'checked'.

Thank you.

Comment: _“And the associated javascript code:”_ - I only see HTML there, where is the actual JavaScript? If that is using a `change` event handler, then you need to be aware that changing a field value or status _via_ JavaScript, does not trigger any such events in the first place. You would have to explicitly _trigger_ the change event handler from within your text function then.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, it's there now

Comment: Try `$('#id_taken_test_before').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');`

Comment: Hmm, that hasn't done it. Thanks though

Comment: `#div_id_taken_test_before` is the wrong selector for the checkbox. Replace with`#div_id_taken_test_before .checkboxinput`.

Comment: That seems correct, but its still not working. Thanks though @SonNguyen